# Is it possible to connect points with specific order in a scatter plot?

Tags: matplotlib, plot, scatter-plot

I have this array containing the points I need to plot:

```
 [[  1.   1.  82. 177.   0.   0.  -1.]
 [  2.   2.  83. 177.   0.   0.   1.]
 [  3.   2.  84. 177.   0.   0.   2.]
 [  4.   2.  85. 177.   0.   0.   3.]
 [  5.   2.  86. 178.   0.   0.   4.]
 [  6.   2.  83. 177.   0.   0.   2.]
 [  7.   2.  84. 177.   0.   0.   6.]
 [  8.   2.  85. 177.   0.   0.   7.]
 [  9.   2.  86. 176.   0.   0.   8.]
 [ 10.   2.  87. 175.   0.   0.   9.]
 [ 11.   2.  86. 174.   0.   0.  10.]
 [ 12.   2.  85. 174.   0.   0.  11.]]
```

each point has an "identifier" indicated in the 1st column, 3rd and 4th ones contain the coordinates of the point while the last column indicate to which point a specific point is connected.

Is there any way to connect these points following this specific order using matplotlib?

Answer (score 0):

Supposing the first column is formed by successive numbers, the index in the array can serve as "identifier" (subtracting 1, as Python works with zero-based array indices).

Therefore, the last column (subtracting 1) indicates the endpoints of the segments that start with the points in the 3rd and 4th column.  Negative edge values can be discarded.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection
import numpy as np

pnts = np.array([[1, 1, 82, 177, 0, 0, -1],
                 [2, 2, 83, 177, 0, 0, 1],
                 [3, 2, 84, 177, 0, 0, 2],
                 [4, 2, 85, 177, 0, 0, 3],
                 [5, 2, 86, 178, 0, 0, 4],
                 [6, 2, 83, 177, 0, 0, 2],
                 [7, 2, 84, 177, 0, 0, 6],
                 [8, 2, 85, 177, 0, 0, 7],
                 [9, 2, 86, 176, 0, 0, 8],
                 [10, 2, 87, 175, 0, 0, 9],
                 [11, 2, 86, 174, 0, 0, 10],
                 [12, 2, 85, 174, 0, 0, 11]])
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 6))
ax.scatter(pnts[:, 2], pnts[:, 3], marker='o', s=100, color='crimson')
edges = pnts[:, -1] - 1  # the last column defines the edges, subtract 1 so they can serve as array index
valid_edges = edges >= 0  # discard all edges with negative indices
# line segments with as first point the 3rd and 4th column of the array, the second point is given 
# via the array of edges; only use valid edges
segments = np.c_[pnts[valid_edges, 2:4], pnts[edges[valid_edges], 2:4]].reshape(-1, 2, 2)
# create a line collection from the given segments
lc = LineCollection(segments, color='blue', linewidth=1)
ax.add_collection(lc)
plt.show()
```

[image: connecting points given list of edges]